# Training speed in GPU vs CPU for LSTM

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks

I was experimenting seq2seq model which was the bi-LSTM encoder/decoder with attention. When I compared the training times on GPU vs CPU while varying the batch size, I got

[image]

1. CPU on the small batch size (32) is fastest. It's even ~1.5 time
   faster than GPU using the same batch size.
2. When I increase the batch size (upto 2000), GPU becomes faster than CPU due to the
   parallelization.

(2) looks reasonable to me. However, I am a bit perplexed by the observation (1). The average sequence length is around 15~20. Even with the batch size 32, I expected that GPU should be faster but it turned out not. I used PyTorch LSTM.

Does it look normal? In RNN-style seq2seq, could CPU be faster than GPU?

Comment: How did you plot that graph? Did you draw it manually? Please, put your **specific** question in the title. Anyway, this could be because, with a smaller batch size, you need to move data more regularly to the GPU, and this could be expensive. However, this is just a guess.